# Previous User not able to see new user

Tags: reactjs, sockets, socket.io

When the new socket is connected, he is able to see the previous socket, but the previous socket is not able to see the new socket.

Backend

```
const users = []

socket.on("add-new-user", (data) => {
users.push(data);
socket.emit("users-list", users); });
```

Frontend

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    socket.on("users-list", (data) => setUsers(data));
    console.log(users);
  }, [socket, users]);

  return (
    <div>
      {users.map((user) => (
        <p key={user.id}>{user.username}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

[image: Prev User can't see new user.]

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer myself, while keep trying. All I need to do is:

```
socket.emit ----> io.emit
```